# Which of the two overlapping graphs will ctx.fill method fill?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fill, stroke

I have two slightly different pieces of code which produce different results. In the first piece, I draw the inside triangle first, then the outside square. In the second piece, I draw the outside square first, then the inside triangle. However, for the second piece of code, the entire square is filled. Why is this happening?

```
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById('c');
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    ctx.moveTo(75 ,75);
    ctx.lineTo(125, 75);
    ctx.lineTo(125, 125);
    ctx.lineTo(75, 75);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(150,50);
    ctx.lineTo(50,150);
    ctx.lineTo(50,50);
    ctx.stroke();

  </script>
</body>
```

[The result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlxI0.png)

```
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById('c');
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(150,50);
    ctx.lineTo(50,150);
    ctx.lineTo(50,50);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.moveTo(75 ,75);
    ctx.lineTo(125, 75);
    ctx.lineTo(125, 125);
    ctx.lineTo(75, 75);
    ctx.fill();

  </script>
</body>
```

[The result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilMhZ.png)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule If you want consistency, use `ctx.beginPath()` when you start a path declaration.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `ctx.beginPath` to clear old path and start a new one.

When you use path construction methods like, `ctx.rect`, `ctx.arc`, `ctx.moveTo`, `ctx.lineTo`, `ctx.quadraticCurveTo`, `ctx.bezierCurveTo`, `ctx.ellipse`, `ctx.arcTo` and `ctx.closePath`  you are adding to the current path held in the 2D context memory.

When you call `ctx.fill` or `ctx.stroke` you render the current stored path. The path stored is continually added to with the 1st paragraphs path constructor methods. The path stays stored until you call `ctx.beginPath` which will clear the current path and start a new one.

*<sub>**Note** that resizing the canvas will also clear the current path and reset the canvas context to its default state, though it is not recommended as a way to revert to the default state.</sub>*

So to correctly render the two paths use `ctx.beginPath` to create a new path for each you want to render.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();  // begin a new path
// Note that the path is offset by 0.5 
// A line is defined by its center. A line 1 pixel wide has half the line
// above and half below. If you render at the pixel boundary from 50,50 to 100,50
// half the line is rendered on the 49th row and half on the 50th row.
// Offsetting by 0.5 ensures the line is rendered on the pixels you want
// producing a better quality line.
ctx.moveTo(50.5, 10.5);
ctx.lineTo(150.5,10.5);
ctx.lineTo(50.5,110.5);
//ctx.lineTo(50,10);
ctx.closePath();  // use this as lineTo does not connect the start and end lines.
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(75 ,75);
ctx.lineTo(125, 75);
ctx.lineTo(125, 125);
ctx.lineTo(75, 75);
// you don't need to use closePath here as fill does not treat continuous path
// segments as special.
ctx.fill();
```

*<sub>**Note** that when you use `ctx.beginPath` the method `ctx.lineTo` acts like `ctx.moveTo` if it is the first method called after the `ctx.beginPath` call. This can help reduce the complexity of rendering functions.</sub>*

#### Correct use of `ctx.closePath`

It is a common mistake to think that `ctx.closePath` is related to `ctx.beginPath`. The function `ctx.closePath` is a path constructor function that adds to the current path by creating a line from the last added point to the last `ctx.moveTo` or first point after a `ctx.beginPath` call.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 400;
ctx.beginPath();  // begin a new path
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100.5, 10.5);
ctx.lineTo(150.5, 110.5);
ctx.lineTo(50.5, 110.5);
ctx.closePath(); // creates a line from (50,110) to (100,10)
ctx.moveTo(300.5, 10.5);
ctx.lineTo(350.5, 110.5);
ctx.lineTo(250.5, 110.5);
ctx.closePath(); // creates a line from (250,110) to (300,10)
ctx.stroke();
```

#### Why use `ctx.closePath()`

The `ctx.closePath` ensures that the ends of the shape are joined as a single path and will be rendered using `ctx.lineJoin` setting. If you don't use it then the path is open and the `ctx.lineCap` setting will be applied to the ends

The snippet shows the difference between `ctx.closePath` and using `ctx.lineTo` to create a line back to the start. Notice the join at the top of the triangle. The left one used `ctx.closePath` and the right used `ctx.lineTo`

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 400;

ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineCap = "butt";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,20);
ctx.lineTo(150,120);
ctx.lineTo(50,120);
ctx.closePath(); // creates a line from (50,210) to (100,20)
// closed path with the line joined at the start
ctx.stroke()

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(250,20);
ctx.lineTo(300,120);
ctx.lineTo(200,120);
ctx.lineTo(250,20);
// path is open the last line back to the start is still open and
// will use ctx.lineCap to render the start and end
ctx.stroke()
```